# git remove all files except some files

Tags: git

I am trying to remove all files from a git branch except 1 file

```
# this removes all files
git rm -rf .
# what should i use to do somthing like that
git rm -rf . --except file1 file2
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't have any local changes in the files you want to keep, it's easiest to first remove all files, and then add the ones back you want to keep:

```
git rm -rf .
git checkout HEAD -- file1 file2
```

If you do have local changes, commit or stash them first.

Comment: isn't out there any oneliner?

Comment: @andreagalle Sure, there is `git rm -rf . && git checkout HEAD -- file1 file2`. (Seriously though, this is a very uncommon thing to do, so what's the problem with two lines?)